# Propel fail in creating an instance of a concrete class with inheritance?

Tags: php, orm, propel

I can't find a way to use `findOrCreate()` with single inheritance and abstract parent class in Propel. This little example gives me a **fatal error**:

> Fatal error: Cannot instantiate abstract class ComicBook
>   propel\query\ModelCriteria.php on line 1181

The **query** that throws this fatal error is fairly simple:

```
$thebook = ComicBookQuery::create()->filterById(1)->findOneOrCreate();
```

A little piece of **database schema**:

```
<table name="book" abstract="true" phpName="AbstractBook">
    <column name="id" type="INTEGER" required="true"
       primaryKey="true" autoIncrement="true"/>
    <column name="type" type="VARCHAR" size="255" required="true"
       inheritance="single">
        <inheritance key="Abstract" class="AbstractBook"/>
        <inheritance key="ComicBook" class="ComicBook" extends="AbstractBook"/>
    </column>
</table>
```

Is there any way to get inheritance working with abstract parent class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue with the single table inheritance is that you always fake things. You get this error because the real model is `AbstractBook`, nothing else...

With `abstract=false`, you'll be able to instanciate an `AbstractBook` (which won't be abstract at all…), and then it will be transformed into a `ComicBook`.

By setting `abstract=true`, you cannot instantiate an `AbstractBook`. Overriding to the rescue!

I didn't dig a lot in the code but, if you want to create `ComicBook` with `findOneOrCreate()`, you'll have to override the following method: `getModelName()` in your `ComicBookQuery` class:

```
<?php

class ComicBookQuery extends BaseComicBookQuery {

    public function getModelName()
    {
        return 'ComicBook';                                                                                                                              
    }

} // ComicBookQuery
```

It's a best practice to override methods to fit your needs ;)

Comment: Thank you, really made my day dude. Of course i need abstract parent class!